# SVG textpath via javascript not drawing

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to generate a simple textPath. I thought this would take me 5 minutes but now it has been a few hours and I've poured over stack overflow and google to find that my implementation looks right. I'm not sure whats missing. I can get a TextNode to attach to a text container but as soon as I put the textPath on it will not render in the SVG element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html="">
<html>  
<meta name="description" content="">
<head>
<script language="Javascript">


function drawTextPath(evt){

var mypath2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","path"); 

mypath2.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "#path");    
mypath2.setAttributeNS(null, "d","M400 50 l200 0");
mypath2.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", "none");
mypath2.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","red");
document.getElementById("bodySVG").appendChild(mypath2);





var text1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
text1.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "blue");
text1.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","30px");
text1.setAttributeNS(null,"x", "0");
text1.setAttributeNS(null,"y", "70");


var textpath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","textPath");
  textpath.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#path");   
  var ringdatenode = document.createTextNode("This is the text");
  textpath.appendChild(ringdatenode);
  text1.appendChild(textpath);
  document.getElementById("bodySVG").appendChild(text1);

}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Welcome </p>

<svg id="bodySVG" height="800" width="1500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">



<circle id="todayring" cx="100" cy="20" r="18" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"    fill="orange" onclick="drawTextPath(evt);"></circle>

</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close. The id should be path and not #path though.

```
mypath2.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "path");
```

which you refer to as #path as you have done.

Comment: That is an amazingly trivial mistake I can't believe I didn't catch. Good eye Mr. Longson.